# How to select a select input after form submission in Jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile

I have a form with a  input.
When I submit my form and go back to it, this input goes back to the default value.

Usually i do this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectCountry').val('<?php echo $country ?>');
});
```

BUT in JQuery mobile, due to Ajax wrapping, $(document).ready does not fire after form submission.

Is there a way to resolve this simple but annoying problem ?

Comment: Are you submitting the form via Ajax?

Comment: I'm submiting my form "normally" 
<form action="/form.php" method="POST">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

It would be better if you can load the value on page load.

```
<select id="selectCountry">
<?php 
foreach ($countries as $country){
   echo '<option value="' . $country . '"';
   if($country == $selectedCountry){
      echo ' selected="selected"';
   }
   echo '>' . $country . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

**Update again**

This is how you do it for jquery mobile.

```
$('#selectCountry').live('pagecreate',function(){
      $(#'selectCountry').val('<?php echo $country; ?>');
   });
```

[See this page.](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

> **Previous suggestion** - Can you use the .live() function?
>
> $('#selectCountry').live(function(){
>        $(#'selectCountry').val('');
>      });

Comment: The documentation I read shows this should have worked. If you can load the value on page load, it would be better anyway.

Comment: I think i will end up using the php way of life.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectCountry').val('<?php echo $country ?>');
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   init()
});

function init() {
    $('#selectCountry').val('<?php echo $country ?>');
}
```

Then at the bottom of your page you can always call init() directly:

```
<script type='text/javascipt'>
init()
</script>
```

Comment: When i submit the form, it's not calling that function. I don't know how jquery mobile manage this.
Maybe it's because i use the same page for the form and the form action i don't know

Comment: It must be using AJAX without you knowing it. You need to find the AJAX call and tack the init() call to the callback function.

Comment: It shouldn't be THAT hard to do such a simple task with jquery mobile ain't it ?